# MATLAB equivalent to Python's string.join()

Tags: matlab

In Python, I can easily join the contents of a list of strings, separated by a set of characters, this way:

```
>>> L = ["A","B","C"]
>>> string.join(L,"_")
'A_B_C'
```

In MATLAB, I can concatenate a cell array of strings this way:

```
>> L = {'A','B','C'};
>> [L{:}] % or strcat(L{:}), with trimming of trailing spaces

ans =

ABC
```

Is there simple command in MATLAB that mimics the ability of string.join to add a separator character?

I'm aware that this can be done through grotesque constructs such as

```
[sprintf('%s_',L{1:end-1}), L{end}]
```

among others, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: +1 for the "grotesque construct". Good enough for me!

Comment: Matlab 2016 has `join({'A','B','C','D'}, ',')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a build-in function like string.join in MATLAB. Your statement with sprintf is probably the best way how it can be done.

Here is another more recent FileExchange submission - [STRJOIN](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin). It probably was based on JOIN from @BenH's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a single command, but strjoin looks very versatile.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: From Matlab 2013a on there is a built-in function called [strjoin](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)

I don't know of any built-in way, but I use this now (I'm assuming that you want to concatenate a 'cell string' and that you do not want to lose trailing spaces):

```
L = {' A',' B ','C '};
delimiter = '/';
append_delimiter = @(in) [in delimiter];
tmp = cellfun(append_delimiter, L(1:end-1), 'UniformOutput', false);
result = horzcat(tmp{:}, L{end})

>>> ans =

A B C
```

Or, the same as a function:

```
function joined_str = strjoin(in_strings, delimiter)
    assert(iscellstr(in_strings), 'strjoin:cellstr', '1st argument: cell string');
    assert(ischar(delimiter) && (isvector(delimiter) || isempty(delimiter)), ...
           'strjoin:string', '2nd argument: string');

    append_delimiter = @(in) [in delimiter];
    appended = cellfun(append_delimiter, in_strings(1:end-1), 'UniformOutput', false);
    joined_str = horzcat(appended{:}, in_strings{end});
end

>> strjoin({' A ', ' B ', ' C '}, '_')

ans =

 A _ B _ C
```

Comment: This is to 'grotesque' as what 'grotesque' is to 'cute'.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [join] found on the file exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4872).

Comment: Thanks. The existence of that submission probably tells me that the answer to my question is "no".